# Where are the db files? at /var/lib/mongodb I cant find any increase in size. I ran very big loop to create lakhs of objects

Tags: mongodb

I am using UBUNTU, from /etc/mongod.conf, I found that /var/lib/mongdb is the path for data.

I have found some files like collectionname.0, .1, .ns in that directory. but when I run a very big loop(lakhs), I am able to get them back using mongo shell, but that mongodb directory size is not increasing, so there must be someother place where this data is being stored

What is that place?

Comment: MongoDB preallocates some data in advance. So it may be perfectly possible that required file space has been allocated already.

For example, if you had a huge collection in a database, but then dropped it.

You should monitor `fileSize` parameter from `db.stats()` as you insert the data. Does it move?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no another place. As indicated by @itsbruce, in Ubuntu it's /var/lib/mongodb.

On a non-packaged installation (on Linux), i.e. without a /etc/mongodb.conf file, the default is /data/db/ (unless otherwise specified).

You can modify the switch "--dbpath" on the command line to designate a different directory for the mongod instance to store its data. Typical locations include: /srv/mongodb, /var/lib/mongodb or /opt/mongodb.

(Windows systems use the \data\db directory.) If you installed using a package management system.

I recommend using the `db.collection.stats` command as outlined [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/collection-statistics/) to monitor the size of your collection as you insert data. The link also explains what each field (in the output) means.

Answer (score 1):

That is the correct data location for MongoDB on Ubuntu.  MongoDB [pre-allocates](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Excessive+Disk+Space) filespace.  Are you sure you have generated more data than would fit into the initial pre-allocated files?  Try blowing away any existing data files and restarting Mongo with the --noprealloc flag.  Then add data.