# It is possible to recover a database in GKE, after service stop (Google Cloud)?

Tags: mongodb, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, persistence

My account in Google Cloud does not have support and Google indicates me to ask here for any issue...

I had a GKE with 2 Nodejs apps and a MongoDB, each in a separate docker, Mongo one with persistence disk of course.

There was an issue with the credit card and the payment and Google stopped my GKE service.
When I entered a correct credit card and paid the bill I was able to see the Compute Engine (VM instances and Storage disks), but not the GKE.

Is there a way to export/download previous MongoDB data in Google Cloud, from the Storage Disk, to recover the information?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post a list of the VMs and Storage instances?  Just want to see what you actually have in your project.

Comment: Does your disk still exist? If yes, then yes

Comment: Was your MongoDB deployed on GKE ? Can you see any GKE cluster on the list of clusters existing within your project ?

Comment: In Compute engine/Storage/Disk the instance of my MongoDB still exists but there is no cluster in the GKE list. Not sure how to export the content of the Storage disk to populate a new MongoDB (in another place).

Comment: Did you try to copy `/var/lib/mongodb` directory ? Compare with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12917122/11714114) answer.

Comment: And to access the disk, you should mount it somewhere e.g. to a new Compute Engine VM instance.

Comment: @AlexAcc did you try solution provided by mario? You still have access to those disks?

Comment: We tried, ando also different options, but it was impossible to recover anything. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you try to create snapshot of you Disk and then use them in new GKE cluster? Something like [here](https://faun.pub/how-to-restore-from-gke-persistent-disk-snapshot-853270364075) Do you still have those disks or you removed them and started from scratch?